# Как отправить в telegram ссылку в виде кнопки через bot api?

Tags: php, telegram

Пишу телеграм бота на php, хочу через бот давать юзеру инвайт-линк в чат, чтобы сама ссылка не была доступна юзеру, только клик по ней. Видел такую кнопку-ссылку у какого-то другого бота, но в документации рыл-рыл, так и не нарыл способа.
Подскажите?..

Answer (score 0):

Формируете ссылку в контенте, например (Чат реальный "Обсуждение Telegram на русском языке.", и это не реклама, а как пример):

```
<a href='https://t.me/joinchat/FCvwtkANkEp4L90h9TzjXQ'>перейти</a>
```